# MH format is special different from both mbox and maildir?

Tags: email

Claws Mail uses the MH format according to [its manual](http://www.claws-mail.org/faq/index.php/Plugins#I_love_maildir_format._Is_there_a_useful_replacement_in_Claws_Mail.2C_which_is_better_than_the_maildir_plugin_.3F).

[Mbox vs Maildir: Mail Storage Formats](http://web.archive.org/web/20181101101025/http://www.linuxmail.info:80/mbox-maildir-mail-storage-formats/) states that

> The Unix world has two ways of storing mail messages, the traditional mbox format and the newer maildir format. Postfix and Dovecot supports the two mail storage format so you can use any format, but I highly recommend you use the maildir format.

Is the MH format used by Claws Mail different from both Mbox and Maildir?
Is a special designed format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MH_Message_Handling_System) is the name of a set of programs used to handle email; their current incarnation is [`nmh`](http://www.nongnu.org/nmh/). The “format” they define, which uses one file per message and a [simple directory layout](https://rand-mh.sourceforge.io/book/overall/audir.html#TheSub), is not the same as either mbox or Maildir. As you mention, this is Claws Mail’s native format.

[Maildir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) is effectively a descendant of MH, fixing a number of problems around synchronisation with its `tmp`, `new` and `cur` sub-directories. MH and Maildir aren’t directly compatible, so Claws Mail on its own can’t use Maildir directories; it has a plugin to add support but it’s unmaintained.

Comment: It means that claws mail can receive email in /home/username/Maildir?

Comment: No, see my update.

Comment: "Maildir is effectively a descendant of MH" - do you only think that, or is there proof for that?

Comment: @cweiske maildir was designed explicitly in reaction to problems in `mbox` and `mh` storage formats: https://web.archive.org/web/19971012032244/http://www.qmail.org/qmail-manual-html/man5/maildir.html. I think that qualifies as "effectively a descendant".

Answer (score 1):

MH is "yet another mail directory" format (one message per one file).

[Dovecot2: MH Mailbox Format](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/MH)
M[H Message Handling System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MH_Message_Handling_System)